# Freemarker Servlet and Struts : access java methods and variables in template

Tags: session, servlets, struts, freemarker

I want to access the Session, Application and Request variables of a Struts web application.
It tells me Session is of type 'HttpSessionHashModel', and looking up the API I saw this class has a method 'isEmpty()'. so I tried for example

```
<#assign a = Session.isEmpty()>
```

but it tells me there is no such element 'Session.isEmpty'.

does anyone have an Idea why it is not working?

In Session there are several classes which I could access via 
`<#assign b = Session["classname"]>` (it tells me `b` is then of type `freemarker.ext.beans.StringModel`), but I can neither call the methods of class `StringModel` nor can I get to the objects and methods stored in 'classname'.

hope someone can help

Comment: What version of Struts? Please provide some more details; how are you integrating Struts/FreeMarker, etc.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer!
the problem is nearly solved, at least in the case of variable b I tried to access methods which didn't exist in the Java code of 'classname'. 
but I'd still be interested why for example
<#assign a = Session.isEmpty()>
doesn't work... do you have an idea?
because normally when I have a java class and put an instance of it in the datamodel, it is possible to call the methods and variables of this class in the template.I use struts1 and integrate Freemarker by putting a servlet 'freemarker' in web.xml and mapping *.ftl files to this servlet.

Comment: Not sure; does `Session.empty` work?

Comment: You have to find out what the actual class of `Session` is. There are two classes here: the original Java class, and the wrapper class of FreeMarker. I know a few dirty tricks for that... `${Session}` *possibly* prints the result of `toString()` which then used to contain the original Java class name. `${Session?root}` will probably make FreeMarker angry, and it will print the wrapper class name into the error message. Oh, and even better, did you try: `<#list Session?keys as k>${k},</#list>`

Comment: thanks for your answer (sorry for delay in answering back..). I have tried your suggestions, so it seems Session is of type HttpSessionHashModel, but I cannot access the methods of this class somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@s` macro:

> Tags distributed with Struts are automatically made available to FreeMarker templates. To use any tag add "@s." in front of the tag name. Like:

```
<@s.if test="printName">
  <@s.property value="myBeanProperty" />
</@s.if>
```

**References**

- [Using Freemarker Templates - Using Struts tags on FreeMarker templates](http://struts.apache.org/docs/using-freemarker-templates.html#UsingFreemarkerTemplates-Tags)